# google chrome appearing border when selecting text

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qd6eR/3/)

In the above fiddle there is no background or border color 
but when I click or select the text border appears in google chrome.

**Markup**

```
<div id="ja-component">
  <div id="fit-scroll" style="height: 505px; overflow: hidden; padding: 0px; width: 289px;" class="jspScrollable" tabindex="0">

  <p>some text</p>


  </div>
</div>
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: There's a reason that you're prompted to enter code, and not just a link to jsfiddle. Hint: it's not a test of your loophole-finding skill.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
*:focus {
    outline: none;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qd6eR/1/)

Comment: In the name of accessibility please don't do this.  Keyboard-only users need to be able to see where their focus is.  I recommend disabling outline on an element-by-element basis and making sure you replace it with an obvious focus styling.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add "outline: 0;" as 'div#fit-scroll" style.
I would recommend not to use inline style, but according to your demo, you should add:

```
div id="fit-scroll" style="box-shadow:0; outline: 0; height: 505px; overflow: hidden; padding: 0px; width: 289px;" class="jspScrollable" tabindex="0">
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qd6eR/)

Answer (score 0):

Chrome puts as default (via user agent stylesheet) this yellow border (which is in fact an outline) around each input element when it is focused.
You can overwrite this default by putting the following code into your css:

```
*:focus {
    outline: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
*:focus {
    outline: none;
}
```

It should do the trick...